# PHP change menu link if user is logged in

Tags: php

I need some help by getting my navbar to replace the login link to logout for users who is logged in. I've tried this code:

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>';
    } 
?>
```

But it don't work. It still shows the Log in button on my navbar.
I've inserted the code in my nav.php
The code in my nav.php looks like this

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>  

        <?php include('include\menuspace.php'); ?>  

        <li><a href='index.php' id='framside' onclick='changeDiv('1')'><span>Framsida</span></a></li>  

        <li><a href='skolen.php' id='skulen'><span>Skulen</span></a></li>  

        <?php include('include\ifnotie.php'); ?>
        <?php include('include\ifie.php'); ?>  

        <li><a href='elevar.php' id='elevrådet' onclick='changeDiv('3')'><span>Elevrådet</span></a></li>  

        <li><a href='ledelsen.php' id='ledelse' onclick='changeDiv('4')'><span>Ledelse</span></a></li>  

        <li><a href='kontakt.php' id='kontakt' onclick='changeDiv('5')'><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>  

        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>';
        } else {
        echo '<li><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>';
        } ?>  

    </ul>
</div>
```

The nav.php is a single file, which i use the code `<?php include'(include/nav.php)'; ?>`
in each php file that requires the navigation bar.

Here is a
[Print Screen of access controlled page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLTMi.png)  that requires you to be logged in to see.

---EDIT---

I did like LotusH said, to change     `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` to     `if(isset($_SESSION['name_of_user']))`

It works until i click the logout button. Then it won't change back to login.

---EDIT-19.04.2012----

Fixed the problem with the logout changing to login, had to put a     session_destroy();

Comment: Do you have a session started?

Comment: did you session_start(); before this piece of code?

Comment: Silly question; are you actually setting `$_SESSION['username']` upon logging in and starting the session (`session_start();`) at the top of the page?

Comment: What output does var_dump($_SESSION); gives? I think you have not started a session

Comment: `session_start();` at the top

Comment: Please use `var_dump($_SESSION)` to inspect `$_SESSION`, paste the output here if you still can't find out the reason.

Comment: probobly a silly question according the session_start(); do i use it in the nav.php or at all .php files that uses that nav.php file?

Comment: @LotusH this is what `var_dum($_SESSION)` outputs:
`array(3) { ["name_of_user"]=> string(13) "Administrator" ["email_of_user"]=> string(19) "ikt-kons-ost@hfk.no" ["usr_7fe2869648"]=> string(13) "Administrator" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output of the `var_dump($_SESSION)`

```
array(3) { 
   ["name_of_user"]=> string(13) "Administrator" 
   ["email_of_user"]=> string(19) "ikt-kons-ost@hfk.no" 
   ["usr_7fe2869648"]=> string(13) "Administrator" 
}
```

in your comment,
you should rewrite `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` as `if(isset($_SESSION['name_of_user']))`

Comment: I would just like to say Thank you :D i fixed it all... it turned out that i was creating the .php files localy on a client (which i already knew) but instead of importing them to the the development server with the IIS installed, i imported them to the virtual server running on the development server :facepalm: i feel so stupid right now xD

Comment: @KennethHardstylezVasquez Glad to help :) `var_dump` and `printr` are great for debugging, using them saves you days to ask questions like this, learn to use them.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the advice, never used var_dump before. I'm still in the learning process of PHP, so i learned more thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

First check you have `start` the `session` or not?
If not then write `session_start();` at the top

then try this code:

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username']!='') {
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: do i put the `seassion_start();` like this:  `<?php
 session_start();
 
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username']!='') {
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>';
    } 
?> `